# Only one time access on a quick action

Tags: administration, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I want to give an access to the users only for one time on quick action button.
Like if they click on the quick action button then for the next time he will not be able to access that button.
Can anyone please help me how can I achieve this requirement?

Comment: Should all users not be able to access this function or just one particular user? Can you explain a little more about what the quick action does?

Comment: See I gave the access to this quick action button to all the users when they click on this then for the next time they should not be able to access this button.

Comment: I think specific per user/record combination will be difficult to achieve without a bunch of custom code. Depending on what the requirements are, I would look for a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Dynamic Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lex_dynamic_actions_highlights_panel.htm&type=5&release=228). You'll need to have a (typically Checkbox) field that tracks that the given action has been performed against the current record. If you do this, you can use this field in the action's visibility expression.

Comment: Can I achieve this requirement with the help of apex?

Comment: You can write an invokable method that is called from a flow-based quick action (though I see no point in this). Fundamentally you must track the execution state in the Salesforce database if relying on server-side. If you only want to disable the button after one execution after each load or refresh of the page you could use a custom button in the page (LWC component) but that is wrong IMHO.

Comment: Thank you so much Phil.